# Web services passing entities as parameters

Tags: web-services, soap

I just designed a web service (code firts approach) with one method with the following signature `getItems(MyEntity myEntity)` The point is that MyEntity has others Entities as properties and so on. Because of this, when the client generates the classes from the **WSDL**, lots of entities are created in the client side besides the xml (WSDL) generated is too complex, the question is; is it rigth to expose the entities of my sistem to the clients?, or should i create a entity with simple values? (int amount, String code, String user) like a facade.

Comment: Are all of the entities going to be used?

Comment: No, at this point only the exposed entity.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend only exposing the properties and objects that you need.  If there are properties on your `MyEntity` class that you will never expect the client to populate, there's no point in including that in the WSDL.

Comment: I'm not inluding this properties (entities) in the WSDL, as i mention before i'm writing code first and the framwork creates de xml, i suposse this is because of the dependency between entities (MyEntity has MyEntity2 and this MyEntity3 and so on).  thank you.